# Vue 3 vue-cli, how to use CDN url for css/js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

How do I configure vue-cli/webpack (vue.config.js) to serve JS/CSS/images from an absolute URL CDN path, ie: `https://abc.cloudfront.net/__data/`.

I only see `publicPath` which isn't helpful, because it doesn't support an absolute URL. I can't put `/__data` because I must serve the index.html from a different domain/webserver, but NOT the assets.

Ie: `index.html` will be served from `example.com`

And it will link to an absolute CDN url like `https://cloudfront.net/abc/image1-hash.jpg`

Comment: Are you sure `baseUrl` [does not support absolute URL](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2877) ?

Comment: @MichalLevý baseUrl is deprecated, it says to use `publicPath`

Comment: yah, I ment `publicPath` not `baseUrl`